# How to get a reference to the object that instantiated a second object in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, object, parent, kvc

A have an object (secondObject) that is an instance of a subclass of NSObject, and within secondObject, I want to get a reference to the object where secondObject was instantiated (firstObject).

Example:

In FirstObject.m (subclass of UIViewController)

```
    SecondObject *secondObject = [[SecondObject alloc] init];
```

in SecondObject.m

```
    @implementation SecondObject
    - (id) init {
        self = [super init];
        NSLog(@"Parent object is of class: %@", [self.parent class]);
    return self;
    }
    @end
```

I was looking for something similar to the .parentViewController property of viewControllers

I have been researching KeyValueCoding, but haven't been able to find a solution.

The workaround I implemented, was to create a initWithParent:(id)parent method in secondObject.m and then pass self at the instantiation.

in SecondObject.m

```
    @interface SecondObject ()
    @property id parent;
    @end

    @implementation SecondObject
    - (id) initWithParent:(id)parent {
        self = [super init];
        self.parent = parent;
        NSLog(@"Parent object is of class: %@", [self.parent class]);
        return self;
    }

    @end
```

And then instantiate the object in the fisrtObject.m as follows

```
    SecondObject *secondObject = [[SecondObject alloc] initWithParent:self];
```

Is there a more straightforward way to do it?

Rgds.... enrique

Comment: What you came up with is the proper way. Or set the property after a call to `init`. Either works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects do not have any sort of pointer to the object that created it.

Your initWithParent: method will work, but you may want to think about why your object needs to know its creator and if there isn't a better way to accomplish whatever you're trying to accomplish.

Also, you're probably going to want to make the parent property a weak property or you're going to end up creating retain cycles all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

It should probably be `_parent = parent;` in that `init` method, but other than that, there's not much wrong with this.  It's actually pretty common as far as I know to do things similar to this (`initWithDelegate:` etc)

However...

It would probably be wise to write a `@protocol` that the `parent` class conforms to, and rather than taking just an `id`, you require an object that conforms to the protocol.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Delegation is a very important design pattern to know. You can read up on it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/Delegation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH14-SW1

Comment: Thx nhgrif...    I implemented @protocols in a different part of the project.   I took this as a challenge, given that what I want to do is conceptually like moving the id delegate from the parent class to the instantiated class, in order to access the delegate <parent> methods and properties.   This is part of a project that uses CoreText (for multiple articles-pages-columns) and includes dynamic font sizing using a pinch gesture, and has the parser and page-columns builder in a separate class branch.